# При запуске android автостартовый .sh скрипт выполняется не полностью

Tags: android, shell, iptables

Добавил скрипт на телефон /system/etc/init.fairnet.sh :

```
#!/system/bin/sh

insmod /system/lib/modules/xt_HL.ko
lsmod > /system/etc/curlsmod
/system/bin/iptables -t mangle -L > /system/etc/preiptables
/system/bin/iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o rmnet+ -j TTL --ttl-set 64
/system/bin/iptables -t mangle -L > /system/etc/postiptables
```

Прошил телефон пересобранным образом ядра, изменив init.sony.rc -
по триггеру завершения загрузки добавил свой сервис fairnet :

```
on property:dev.bootcomplete=1
    start fota-snoop # системный сервис
    start fota-trigger # системный сервис
    start startup-prober # системный сервис
    start fairnet # мой сервис
```

сам сервис:

```
service fairnet /system/bin/sh /system/etc/init.fairnet.sh
    user root
    group root
    disabled
    oneshot
```

права и пользователь скрипта:

```
-rw-r--r-- root     root          280 2018-01-09 01:03 init.fairnet.sh
```

Самая интересная штука, что при запуске вроде скрипт действительно исполняется, но только частично, т.к. модуль xt_HL.ko действительно загружается, а вот файлы вывода не создаются, и правила iptables также не меняются. Если выполнить скрипт вручную после запуска системы, то все ок, но при загрузке выполняется только первая команда скрипта, я в недоумении как вообще это возможно, чтобы скрипт выполнялся частично. Скорее всего остальные команды просто не валидны при выполнении из загрузки, но я не могу понять почему.

Comment: возможно iptables переинициализируется позже выполнения скрипта, сбрасывая настройки на дефолтные?

Comment: я тоже об этом подумал, возможно так оно и есть, поэтому я добавил "дебажные" строки вывода в файл, но и они не работают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена!

Главным виновником оказался SELinux.

```
dmesg | grep iptables
```

на выхлопе выдавал

```
<36>[   39.819005] type=1400 audit(1516096993.541:9): avc: denied { create } for pid=2652 comm="iptables" lport=255 scontext=u:r:init_shell:s0 tcontext=u:r:init_shell:s0 tclass=rawip_socket op_res=-13 ppid=2640 pcomm="sh" tgid=2640 tgcomm="sh"
```

значит в текущей политке /sepolicy не хватало правила, разрешающего выполнение отклоненной операции (команда /system/bin/iptables) на этапе загрузки ОС.

Для добавления нужного правила использовалась утилита [sepolicy-inject](https://bitbucket.org/joshua_brindle/sepolicy-inject), для ее сборки также необходима библитека /usr/lib/libsepol.a, входящая в состав пакета [libsepol1-dev](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/mipsel/libsepol1-dev). Также можно использовать готовый собранный [вариант](https://forum.xda-developers.com/devdb/project/dl/?id=26279) для всех архитектур (мне не помогло, пришлось собирать самому).

```
./sepolicy-inject -s init_shell -t init_shell -c rawip_socket -p getopt,create,setopt -P sepolicy -o sepolicy_new
```

добавляет нужное правило и создает новый sepolicy_new из старого sepolicy с девайса.

Прошиваем девайс новым собранным ядром с новой политикой, для сборки я использовал [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775) для Win.

Готово! Теперь при загрузке телефона скрипт выполняется польностью.

P.S. Свой сервис я переместил из init.sony.rc в init.qcom.rc, а также убрал строки group root и disabled, но сделал это по идейным соображениям и это никак не решает проблему.

P.P.S. Возможно проблема также решается переведением SELinux в режим Permissive, но я не хотел лишаться этой защиты.